# D3 animation in winjs windows app

Tags: javascript, d3.js, winjs

I have created a simple app in visual studio which consists of a force layout network with around 100 nodes.

I ran it in browser and it works fine, no 'lagging' and the browser can handle it very well (chrome). However when running it in a windows app, it doesn't seem powerful enough, it's glitchy and jitters. Is there a reason for this ? Is there a way to get the app to handle the library's animation better ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you targeting Windows 8.1 or Windows 10? Win 8 uses IE11 engine to render apps written in HTML/JS where Win 10 uses Edge engine. I did couple times some performance profiling of the web app I'm working on at work, and IE11 is around 3x times slower than Chrome engine. Especially when it comes to DOM manipulations which in IE11 can be much slower. For example access to the node's `innerWidth` value in IE takes on average 80 msec.

Comment: I am using windows 10. Yeah I did notice IE is a lot slower than Chrome. But your point about the app using IE/Edge engine makes sense. Do you know if it's possible to integrate the chrome engine with my windows app ? I researched a little and found out about 'chrome embedded', do you have any knowledge of this ? : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_Embedded_Framework

Comment: I don't think it's possible to embed Chrome engine. It's up to the Win 10 how it runs and manage apps. I haven't used D3.js embedded in the UWP app but the Edge engine is much faster than IE11 and in many benchmarks it's as fast as Chrome's engine.